# Freeswitch 1.10 instance is failing to hang up the call after sending a fax

Tags: freeswitch

I am setting up a new Freeswitch v1.10 system, and one of the tasks needed is to send faxes out over our SIP lines.

This is triggered via ESL using the "originate" command:
originate {origination_caller_id_number=61xxxxxxxxxx,fax_header='To: Test Fax From: Me',fax_ident='61xxxxxxxxx',fax_disable_v17=false,fax_enable_t38=true,fax_enable_t38_request=true,ignore_early_media=true,absolute_codec_string='PCMA,PCMU',fax_verbose=true,fax_use_ecm=true}sofia/gateway/SIPxxxx.com/61xxxxxxxxx &txfax(/xxpathxx/output.tif)"

The fax all sends correctly and is received at the other end, but the connection is never hung up.  No SIP BYE command or anything is sent.

I have this working fine on another system under Freeswitch 1.6, and as far as I can tell, my config is pretty much the same between systems.

Any suggestions of things to try is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it may be a bug, but could also be something with config. The first thing to test would be trying without ESL, direct from FreeSWITCH, to see if it replicates.
Either way, it's worth opening an issue on the FreeSWITCH repo so the team can get the info on this from you directly and follow up more easily. I took a look through the existing issues and don't see anything for missing SIP BYEs specifically or FAX connections misbehaving, so you'll need to open a new issue for this! https://github.com/signalwire/freeswitch/issues